# Ubuntu menu won't close after opening

Tags: 20.04, appmenu

Today I am having problems with the Ubuntu menu.

when I log in and open it, it goes into a state where it doesn't bring up the icons and has a odd black panel at the right with 3 dots.

when I try to close it by pressing the windows key on my keyboard or by clicking on the menu it animates closing the icons (even though they aren't there to start with) and then goes back into the state when I opened it.

I can launch programs but they are unresponsive and have a name and close button at the top left corner of my screen.

I am using dash to dock and Ubuntu 20.04.1

I need a way fix this quick as I can't use my app menu for anything without having to log off and back on again

EDIT: I now realize dash to dock is the thing causing the problem.
if I disable it and reenable the default ubuntu bar it works fine.

I still would like to know how to fix it though.
I don't really like having two docks